# Fail to get an id of a button (Kivy and Python)

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to get an id from a button in my code, but i cant find a way to do that. This button have a feature of long_touch, its create a loop while the button is pressed, and print "Loop!" every 0.5 sec.I need to do many functions, and each one depends of whats button is pressed. EX: if the button 1 is pressed -> go.function 1.

The best i cant get is: {'lbl_txt': <WeakProxy to <kivymd.uix.label.MDIcon object at 0x7f491087ac80>>}  from self.ids, and i feel happy when i get it on the first time, but i found out that this value float every debug, and make me bad again.
Can someone help me?

```
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import TouchBehavior
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class MainApp(MDApp):   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)          
        self.kv =Builder.load_file('kv file') # Arquivo Kivy
        Window.maximize() # Tamanho inicial da janela
        
    def build(self):
        return self.kv

#Funcao para reconhecer e iniciar Hold_ltbLeftJ1Button -> Movimento continuo
class LongTouchButton(MDIconButton, TouchBehavior): 
    '''Class implement'''
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.duration_long_touch = 2    #Duracao para iniciar a funcao long touch

    def on_long_touch(self,*args):
        #MainApp.get_id(self)
        stringID = self.ids
        print(stringID)
        self.m = True
        self.while_long()

    def on_release(self, *args):
        self.m = False

    def while_long(self, *args):
        if self.m:
            print("LOOP!")
            Clock.schedule_once(self.while_long, .5)  #Cria o clock enquanto self.m = true e seta o intervalo de tempo para .5s
    
    def prints(self,*args):
        if(self.ids.bt1.text == "bt1"):         #i try this way - > not work, why?
            print("BUTTON 1 IS PRESSED")
        if(self.ids == "bt2"):                  #i try this another way, dont work
            print("BUTTON IS PRESSED")

if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Now the .kv file

```
FloatLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDToolbar:
        title: "ACESS TO ID WITH PROBLEM"
        text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        md_bg_color: 0, 0.3, 0.6, 1
        
    MDFloatLayout:              
        LongTouchButton:
            id: bt1
            text: "self.id"
            user_font_size : 80
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "center_y": .5}
            on_press: self.prints()
        
        LongTouchButton:
            id: bt2
            text: "self.id"
            user_font_size : 80
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .7, "center_y": .5}
            on_press: self.prints()
```

Comment: The `id` is not stored as part of the `LongTouchButton`. you must use something else in your `prints()` method logic. Your can use the `text` property of the `LongTouchButton`, or you can add a new attribute to the `LongTouchButton` (perhaps, for example, `my_button_no: 1`), and use that in the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can add an attribute to the `LongTouchButton`:

```
FloatLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDToolbar:
        title: "ACESS TO ID WITH PROBLEM"
        text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        md_bg_color: 0, 0.3, 0.6, 1
        
    MDFloatLayout:              
        LongTouchButton:
            id: bt1
            text: "self.id"
            my_butt_no: 1
            user_font_size : 80
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "center_y": .5}
            on_press: self.prints()
        
        LongTouchButton:
            id: bt2
            text: "self.id"
            my_butt_no: 2
            user_font_size : 80
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .7, "center_y": .5}
            on_press: self.prints()
```

Then use that in the `prints()` method:

```
def prints(self, *args):
    # if (self.ids.bt1.text == "bt1"):  # i try this way - > not work, why?
    #     print("BUTTON 1 IS PRESSED")
    # if (self.ids == "bt2"):  # i try this another way, dont work
    #     print("BUTTON IS PRESSED")
    if self.my_butt_no == 1:
        print("BUTTON 1 IS PRESSED")
    if self.my_butt_no == 2:
        print("BUTTON 2 IS PRESSED")
```

Comment: It Works! I was tryind to do something like that, but as you can see, i was using a self.ids.newAtribute , now i see. Thanks John Anderson, you`re awesome!